# Function on selection of worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA function to get a function ("Rollup") to update values of a range when the worksheet is selected.

I have this repeated for different sheets in the specific sheet codes, but **I'm lost as to how to create a single function** that will take the sheetname with the range name (e.g. "rngXF") and the value for the rollup function (e.g. "XF")

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim c As Range
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each c In Range("rngXF")
    c.Value = Rollup(c, "XF")
Next c

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: just a thought, create a sub with parameters for sheetname and range and then trigger it using the activate and pass the values to the sub to actually do it

Comment: 1) This Function "Rollup" is already implemented? 2) you can create a sub with input parameters like so: (Sub Test(ByVal param1 as Integer, ByVal param2 as String)).

Comment: @MarcoGetrost Yes - it sums up the values of specific cells on other sheets with sheetnames containing 'x'. Where would the sub be placed?

Comment: Sounds like you want something in Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object). It's a method of the Workbook, but it should be triggered every time you activate one of the sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place this in any sheet module that you want the RollUp to work :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call Calculate_RollUp(Me, "rngXF", "XF")
End Sub
```

And place this in a regular module :

```
Public Sub Calculate_RollUp(SheetObject As Worksheet, Range_Name As String, RollUp_Argument As String)
Dim c As Range
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In SheetObject.Range(Range_Name)
        c.Value = Rollup(c, RollUp_Argument)
    Next c


    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .Calculate
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```